# how to create a template class that has two variables which we will take input from users and that the input values may be of any type

Tags: c++

how to create a template class that has two variables which we will take input from users and that the input values may be of any type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Calculator
{
    T value1;
    T value2;
    T memory;
public:
    T inValue()
    {
        cout<<"Value 1: ";  
        cin>>value1;       //I want to take input of int type value
        cout<<"Value 2: ";
        cin>>value2;       //I want to take input of double type value 
        cout<<endl;
    }
    T getValue1()
    {
        return value1;
    }
    T getValue2()
    {
        return value2;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Calculator<int> c;
    c.inValue();
    cout<<c.getValue1()<<endl;
    cout<<c.getValue2()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You can have more than one parameter in your template.  e.g. `template <typename T1, typename T2> class Calculator { ... };`.

Comment: If *either* value can be of *"any type"*, you're assumption they're both of the *same* time with a single template type parameter doesn't make sense. Further, this almost looks like it should be a function with deduced parameter types rather than a class, but its early here and I'm probably experiencing pre-coffee fog.

Answer (score 6):

You need to take two template arguments:

```
template <class T, class U>
```

Then you can use `T` for the first variable and `U` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You may use two template arguments instead of one. This code works: http://ideone.com/cP616m

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T1, class T2>
class Calculator
{
    T1 value1;
    T2 value2;
public:
    void inValue()
    {
        cout<<"Value 1: ";  
        cin>>value1;       //I want to take input of int type value
        cout<<"Value 2: ";
        cin>>value2;       //I want to take input of double type value 
        cout<<endl;
    }
    T1 getValue1()
    {
        return value1;
    }
    T2 getValue2()
    {
        return value2;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Calculator<int, double> c;
    c.inValue();
    cout<<c.getValue1()<<endl;
    cout<<c.getValue2()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to quote [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774316/how-to-create-a-template-class-that-has-two-variables-which-we-will-take-input-f#comment31137514_20774316):

> If either value can be of "any type", you're assumption they're both
>   of the same time with a single template type parameter doesn't make
>   sense. Further, this almost looks like it should be a function with
>   deduced parameter types rather than a class, ...

Yes, you can simply add two parameter types to your class, but it doesn't make sense to have a Calculator instance that's restricted to an `int` and a `double`. Instead you want automatic type deduction for your functions so 1) you don't have to specify the types, 2) it will work for whatever type you want.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(42, 42.0);
}
```